# Kernel crashing at native_smp_send_reschedule smp.c:24

Tags: linux, kernel

I just compiled a kernel from the latest sources in git. Following the instructions of LFS to the end. When a I try to boot the new kernel it always crashes in this function. Its not even a panic, it just a warn but the system doesn't start.

I doesn't happen in QEMU V Machine
It's a 32 bit compilation

I have not achieved to copy the full stack, by pen a paper I got the last frame.

I'm using default configs of X86_64 (Build machine is 64 bits)

```
static void native_smp_send_reschedule(int cpu)
{
    if (unlikely(cpu_is_offline(cpu))) {
        WARN_ON(1);  //<-- Crash here
        return;
    }
    apic->send_IPI_mask(cpumask_of(cpu), RESCHEDULE_VECTOR);
}
```

Comment: I just started getting this on nixos with linux 4.9.31.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've re-installed linux too many times on this box so now I am thinking the actual CPU has a flaw. After all this computer was a "gift computer" from a business. So maybe there was a reason it was free of charge machine.
[image]